# Unable to get the <p> tag with a specific text using xpath() in Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, mocha.js

I have a script which I am trying to run on Selenium environment using Mocha:

```
var assert = require('assert');
var test = require('selenium-webdriver/testing');
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var By = webdriver.By;
var until = webdriver.until;
var equals = webdriver.equals;

test.describe('TrackRevenue Test', function() 
{
  test.it('should work', function() 
  {
        var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
                    .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.phantomjs())
                    .build();
        var loginFlag = 0;
        var baseUrl = 'http://saswatr3.ouh.co/login';
        var expectedTitle = "Track Revenue";
        var successMessage = "Welcome to the admin page!";
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        driver.getTitle().then(function(title) 
        {
            if(expectedTitle === title)
            {
                console.log("Verification Successful - The correct title is displayed on the web page.");
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("Verification Failed - An incorrect title is displayed on the web page.");
            }
        });
        driver.findElement(By.id('username')).sendKeys('saswat@matrixnmedia.com');
        driver.findElement(By.id('password')).sendKeys('DarkPrince2012');
        driver.findElement(By.id('_submit')).click();
        driver.wait(until.titleIs('Track Revenue'), 1000);
        if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//p[text()[contains(.,'Welcome to the admin page!')]]")).size() != 0)
        {

            loginFlag = 1;
        }

        if(loginFlag ==1)
                console.log("Login Successful");
            else
                console.log("Login Unsuccessful");
    driver.quit();
  });
});
```

Using the following code, I am trying to check if a `<p>` tag is present having the text "*Welcome to the admin page!*"

```
if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//p[text()[contains(.,'Welcome to the admin page!')]]")).size() != 0)
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\testPhantomJS\node_modules\selenium-webdriver>mocha -t 50000 testMocha\login-as-administrator-mocha.js


  TrackRevenue Test
Verification Successful - The correct title is displayed on the web page.
    1) should work


  0 passing (21s)
  1 failing

  1) TrackRevenue Test should work:
     TypeError: undefined is not a function
  From: Task: TrackRevenue Test should work
```

What wrong am I doing?

Here is the HTML for the `<p>` which I am trying to find:

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeIn">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-centered col-xs-12">
     <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
     <div class="ibox-title">
       <h5>Links</h5>
       <div class="ibox-tools"> </div>
     </div>
     <div class="ibox-content">
        <p>Welcome to the admin page!</p>
        <p>Please use the menu on the left</p>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on a line that you know works and step through the code until you find the problem. When you find out what code isn't working, post that here and ask the question again.

Comment: How can I achieve that? Can you please guide me? I am new in this environment, and I am getting confused.

Comment: You should google how to add and use breakpoints in the IDE that you are using. I can't guide you through all that here.

Comment: @Saswat I think it's not about XPath expression because the error message said 'undefined is not a function'. driver.findElements() always return a collection although it cannot find the element. So the error should be from another line of code.

Answer (score 2):

Please, try this XPath:

```
"//*[text()[contains(., 'Welcome to the admin page!')]]"
```

Ivo.

Answer (score 0):

"One more option:

```
IList<IWebElement> element = driver.FindElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='ibox-content']/p")

foreach(IWebElement e in element)
if(e.Text.contains("Welcome to the admin page!"))
// do stuff
```

Comment: I already used a forEach loop before. To eliminate using the forEach loop, I have changed my code to the current one

Comment: //p[contains(text(), 'Welcome to the admin page!')]

Comment: Still getting error. TypeError: undefined is not a function